# Using a list of urls in R, How to web scrape images, download the files and group the images back to original url?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a vector  of URLs

```
library(rvest)
URLs <-c("https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31287940/norris-made-step-says-mclaren",
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31287893/vettel-calls-fia-not-very-professional-imola-penalty",
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31284743/alonso-promoted-points-finish-raikkonen-penalty")
```

I would like to loop through these and create a list of image links for all the pictures on that page, with the landing page being the name of the element in the list.  I then want the images to be downloaded with both the image and landing page urls attached.

The current code I have only works for one page at a time.

Single URL for REPREX

```
url <-c("https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31287940/norris-made-step-says-mclaren")
webpage <- html_session(url)
link.titles <- webpage %>% html_nodes("img")
img.url <- link.titles[2] %>% html_attr("src")

### Issue #1 i could not figure out the loop with html_attr to spit out all of the urls in a list###
download.file(img.url, "test.jpg", mode = "wb")

###Issue #2 because of this I cannot loop through a list and download the names###
```

Once I have the ability to download the lists of pictures, the url issue can be solved easily by naming the file with delimeter separating the landing page and the image url.  I could create an ID for each URL to cut down on file length. naming convention, "LP1-ESPN.com.jpg"

The purpose of this would be to quickly go through the pictures of each link, delete irrelevant photos, count the number of photos per link and then link the count(after manual removal of irrelevant photos) and links back to the original dataset which has other metrics for analysis.  This is the reason why I want the naming convention the way it is above so I can just load the remaining names and links from the folder in r without having to manipulate jpg files.

EDIT: I have been able to get a list of all of my urls and the image links within them.  I cannot download them through this loop.. a lot are missing.
The following code works but only downloads maybe 10 percent of the images.  I know that a html_session can fix this but there are approximately 2500 image links and I cant figure out how to loop through with sessions. maybe a while loop?

```
tryCatch(lapply(1:length(total_urls.2$V1), function(x) 
  download.file(new_df[[x]],paste0(total_urls.2[x,3],"_", total_urls.2[x,4],".jpeg"),method = "auto" ,mode = "wb", cacheOK = FALSE)), error = function(e) NULL)
```

Here is the data.frame in question:  it is 2380 lines long but here is the truncated at 50 lines.  I would like to know how to download all of the image links, right now I am only getting about 19 pictures in the folder.

```
dput(total_urls.2[1:50,])
structure(list(V1 = c("https://a3.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fredesign%2Fassets%2Fimg%2Ficons%2FESPN%2Dicon%2Dnascar.png&w=80&h=80&scale=crop&cquality=40&location=origin", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/columnists/edmondson_laurence_m.jpg&h=80&w=80&scale=crop", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/photo/2021/0418/r842329_1296x1296_1-1.jpg&w=130&h=130&scale=crop&location=center", 
"https://a3.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fredesign%2Fassets%2Fimg%2Ficons%2FESPN%2Dicon%2Dnascar.png&w=80&h=80&scale=crop&cquality=40&location=origin", 
"https://a3.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fredesign%2Fassets%2Fimg%2Ficons%2FESPN%2Dicon%2Dnascar.png&w=80&h=80&scale=crop&cquality=40&location=origin", 
"https://a3.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fredesign%2Fassets%2Fimg%2Ficons%2FESPN%2Dicon%2Dnascar.png&w=80&h=80&scale=crop&cquality=40&location=origin", 
"https://a3.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fredesign%2Fassets%2Fimg%2Ficons%2FESPN%2Dicon%2Dnascar.png&w=80&h=80&scale=crop&cquality=40&location=origin", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/columnists/edmondson_laurence_m.jpg&h=80&w=80&scale=crop", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/photo/2021/0418/r842215_1296x1296_1-1.jpg&w=130&h=130&scale=crop&location=center", 
"https://a3.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fredesign%2Fassets%2Fimg%2Ficons%2FESPN%2Dicon%2Dnascar.png&w=80&h=80&scale=crop&cquality=40&location=origin", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/icons/in_15.png", "https://a.espncdn.com/icons/in_15.png", 
"https://a3.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fredesign%2Fassets%2Fimg%2Ficons%2FESPN%2Dicon%2Dnascar.png&w=80&h=80&scale=crop&cquality=40&location=origin", 
"https://a3.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fredesign%2Fassets%2Fimg%2Ficons%2FESPN%2Dicon%2Dnascar.png&w=80&h=80&scale=crop&cquality=40&location=origin", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/photo/2021/0417/r841759_1296x1296_1-1.jpg&w=130&h=130&scale=crop&location=center", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/photo/2021/0331/r834376_1296x1296_1-1.jpg&w=130&h=130&scale=crop&location=center", 
"https://a3.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fredesign%2Fassets%2Fimg%2Ficons%2FESPN%2Dicon%2Dnascar.png&w=80&h=80&scale=crop&cquality=40&location=origin", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/photo/2021/0417/r841759_1296x1296_1-1.jpg&w=130&h=130&scale=crop&location=center", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/photo/2021/0331/r834376_1296x1296_1-1.jpg&w=130&h=130&scale=crop&location=center", 
"https://a3.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fredesign%2Fassets%2Fimg%2Ficons%2FESPN%2Dicon%2Dnascar.png&w=80&h=80&scale=crop&cquality=40&location=origin", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/columnists/edmondson_laurence_m.jpg&h=80&w=80&scale=crop", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/columnists/saunders_nate_m.jpg&h=80&w=80&scale=crop", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/icons/in_15.png", "https://a.espncdn.com/icons/in_15.png", 
"https://a3.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fredesign%2Fassets%2Fimg%2Ficons%2FESPN%2Dicon%2Dnascar.png&w=80&h=80&scale=crop&cquality=40&location=origin", 
"https://a3.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fredesign%2Fassets%2Fimg%2Ficons%2FESPN%2Dicon%2Dnascar.png&w=80&h=80&scale=crop&cquality=40&location=origin", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/columnists/edmondson_laurence_m.jpg&h=80&w=80&scale=crop", 
"https://a3.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fredesign%2Fassets%2Fimg%2Ficons%2FESPN%2Dicon%2Dnascar.png&w=80&h=80&scale=crop&cquality=40&location=origin", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/photo/2021/0329/r833584_1296x1296_1-1.jpg&w=130&h=130&scale=crop&location=center", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/photo/2021/0415/r840887_1296x1296_1-1.jpg&w=130&h=130&scale=crop&location=center", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/icons/in_15.png", "https://a.espncdn.com/icons/in_15.png", 
"https://a3.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fredesign%2Fassets%2Fimg%2Ficons%2FESPN%2Dicon%2Dnascar.png&w=80&h=80&scale=crop&cquality=40&location=origin", 
"https://a3.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fredesign%2Fassets%2Fimg%2Ficons%2FESPN%2Dicon%2Dnascar.png&w=80&h=80&scale=crop&cquality=40&location=origin", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/photo/2021/0415/r840882_1296x1296_1-1.jpg&w=130&h=130&scale=crop&location=center", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/photo/2021/0415/r840887_1296x1296_1-1.jpg&w=130&h=130&scale=crop&location=center", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/icons/in_15.png", "https://a.espncdn.com/icons/in_15.png", 
"https://a3.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fredesign%2Fassets%2Fimg%2Ficons%2FESPN%2Dicon%2Dnascar.png&w=80&h=80&scale=crop&cquality=40&location=origin", 
"https://a3.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fredesign%2Fassets%2Fimg%2Ficons%2FESPN%2Dicon%2Dnascar.png&w=80&h=80&scale=crop&cquality=40&location=origin", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/photo/2021/0413/r839738_1296x1296_1-1.jpg&w=130&h=130&scale=crop&location=center", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/photo/2021/0415/r840882_1296x1296_1-1.jpg&w=130&h=130&scale=crop&location=center", 
"https://a3.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fredesign%2Fassets%2Fimg%2Ficons%2FESPN%2Dicon%2Dnascar.png&w=80&h=80&scale=crop&cquality=40&location=origin", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/photo/2021/0329/r833489_1296x1296_1-1.jpg&w=130&h=130&scale=crop&location=center", 
"https://ca-times.brightspotcdn.com/dims4/default/331b349/2147483647/strip/true/crop/3937x2625+0+0/resize/840x560!/quality/90/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcalifornia-times-brightspot.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fb3%2F61%2F0c10c4344ce0a69870cf8864cf98%2Fitaly-emilia-romagna-f1-gp-auto-racing-58053.jpg", 
"//cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200809102318-verstappen-celeb-exlarge-169.jpg", 
"//cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200809102318-verstappen-celeb-exlarge-169.jpg", 
"//cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200809102318-verstappen-celeb-large-169.jpg", 
"//cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/210309145427-mick-and-michael-schumacher-large-169.jpg", 
"//cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/210305121558-stephanie-travers-lewis-hamilton-large-169.jpg"
), URLs = c("https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31289705/the-blame-game-analysis-bottas-russell-clash-happens-next1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31289705/the-blame-game-analysis-bottas-russell-clash-happens-next2", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31289705/the-blame-game-analysis-bottas-russell-clash-happens-next3", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31287940/norris-made-step-says-mclaren1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31287893/vettel-calls-fia-not-very-professional-imola-penalty1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31284743/alonso-promoted-points-finish-raikkonen-penalty1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31284241/russell-lost-sight-bigger-picture-bottas-clash1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31284241/russell-lost-sight-bigger-picture-bottas-clash2", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31284241/russell-lost-sight-bigger-picture-bottas-clash3", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31283343/russell-asked-bottas-trying-kill-us-both1", 
"http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312812861", "http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312812862", 
"http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312812863", "https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31281017/f1-confirms-race-miami-20221", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31281017/f1-confirms-race-miami-20222", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31281017/f1-confirms-race-miami-20223", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31281017/f1-hold-miami-grand-prix-2022-onwards1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31281017/f1-hold-miami-grand-prix-2022-onwards2", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31281017/f1-hold-miami-grand-prix-2022-onwards3", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31275927/how-hamilton-mercedes-turned-tables-red-bull1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31275927/how-hamilton-mercedes-turned-tables-red-bull2", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31275927/how-hamilton-mercedes-turned-tables-red-bull3", 
"http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312742341", "http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312742342", 
"http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312742343", "https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31270294/has-mercedes-regained-advantage-already-ferrari-spring-surprise1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31270294/has-mercedes-regained-advantage-already-ferrari-spring-surprise2", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31270374/aston-martin-wants-aero-rules-revision1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31270374/aston-martin-wants-aero-rules-revision2", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31270374/aston-martin-wants-aero-rules-revision3", 
"http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312676841", "http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312676842", 
"http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312676843", "https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31263611/hamilton-says-f1-rivalry-vettel-remains-favourite1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31263611/hamilton-says-f1-rivalry-vettel-remains-favourite2", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31263611/hamilton-says-f1-rivalry-vettel-remains-favourite3", 
"http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312634771", "http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312634772", 
"http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312634773", "https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31263349/mercedes-gone-hunted-hunters1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31263349/mercedes-gone-hunted-hunters2", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31263349/mercedes-gone-hunted-hunters3", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31263278/verstappen-calls-clarity-messy-track-limits-rules1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31263278/verstappen-calls-clarity-messy-track-limits-rules2", 
"https://www.latimes.com/sports/story/2021-04-18/max-verstappen-lewis-hamilton-emilia-romagna-grand-prix1", 
"https://edition.cnn.com/2021/04/18/motorsport/max-verstappen-lewis-hamilton-imola-gp-spt-intl/index.html1", 
"https://edition.cnn.com/2021/04/18/motorsport/max-verstappen-lewis-hamilton-imola-gp-spt-intl/index.html2", 
"https://edition.cnn.com/2021/04/18/motorsport/max-verstappen-lewis-hamilton-imola-gp-spt-intl/index.html4", 
"https://edition.cnn.com/2021/04/18/motorsport/max-verstappen-lewis-hamilton-imola-gp-spt-intl/index.html6", 
"https://edition.cnn.com/2021/04/18/motorsport/max-verstappen-lewis-hamilton-imola-gp-spt-intl/index.html8"
), Article_URL = c("IMESP1", "IMESP2", "IMESP3", "IMESP4", "IMESP5", 
"IMESP6", "IMESP7", "IMESP8", "IMESP9", "IMESP10", "IMESP11", 
"IMESP12", "IMESP13", "IMESP14", "IMESP15", "IMESP16", "IMESP17", 
"IMESP18", "IMESP19", "IMESP20", "IMESP21", "IMESP22", "IMESP23", 
"IMESP24", "IMESP25", "IMESP26", "IMESP27", "IMESP28", "IMESP29", 
"IMESP30", "IMESP31", "IMESP32", "IMESP33", "IMESP34", "IMESP35", 
"IMESP36", "IMESP37", "IMESP38", "IMESP39", "IMESP40", "IMESP41", 
"IMESP42", "IMESP43", "IMESP44", "IMESP45", "IMESP62", "IMESP63", 
"IMESP65", "IMESP67", "IMESP69"), img_URL = c("img21", "img22", 
"img23", "img24", "img25", "img26", "img27", "img28", "img29", 
"img210", "img211", "img212", "img213", "img214", "img215", "img216", 
"img217", "img218", "img219", "img220", "img221", "img222", "img223", 
"img224", "img225", "img226", "img227", "img228", "img229", "img230", 
"img231", "img232", "img233", "img234", "img235", "img236", "img237", 
"img238", "img239", "img240", "img241", "img242", "img243", "img244", 
"img245", "img262", "img263", "img265", "img267", "img269")), row.names = c("https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31289705/the-blame-game-analysis-bottas-russell-clash-happens-next1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31289705/the-blame-game-analysis-bottas-russell-clash-happens-next2", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31289705/the-blame-game-analysis-bottas-russell-clash-happens-next3", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31287940/norris-made-step-says-mclaren1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31287893/vettel-calls-fia-not-very-professional-imola-penalty1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31284743/alonso-promoted-points-finish-raikkonen-penalty1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31284241/russell-lost-sight-bigger-picture-bottas-clash1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31284241/russell-lost-sight-bigger-picture-bottas-clash2", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31284241/russell-lost-sight-bigger-picture-bottas-clash3", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31283343/russell-asked-bottas-trying-kill-us-both1", 
"http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312812861", "http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312812862", 
"http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312812863", "https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31281017/f1-confirms-race-miami-20221", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31281017/f1-confirms-race-miami-20222", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31281017/f1-confirms-race-miami-20223", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31281017/f1-hold-miami-grand-prix-2022-onwards1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31281017/f1-hold-miami-grand-prix-2022-onwards2", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31281017/f1-hold-miami-grand-prix-2022-onwards3", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31275927/how-hamilton-mercedes-turned-tables-red-bull1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31275927/how-hamilton-mercedes-turned-tables-red-bull2", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31275927/how-hamilton-mercedes-turned-tables-red-bull3", 
"http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312742341", "http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312742342", 
"http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312742343", "https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31270294/has-mercedes-regained-advantage-already-ferrari-spring-surprise1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31270294/has-mercedes-regained-advantage-already-ferrari-spring-surprise2", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31270374/aston-martin-wants-aero-rules-revision1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31270374/aston-martin-wants-aero-rules-revision2", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31270374/aston-martin-wants-aero-rules-revision3", 
"http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312676841", "http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312676842", 
"http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312676843", "https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31263611/hamilton-says-f1-rivalry-vettel-remains-favourite1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31263611/hamilton-says-f1-rivalry-vettel-remains-favourite2", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31263611/hamilton-says-f1-rivalry-vettel-remains-favourite3", 
"http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312634771", "http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312634772", 
"http://www.espn.com/espn/wire?section=rpm&id=312634773", "https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31263349/mercedes-gone-hunted-hunters1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31263349/mercedes-gone-hunted-hunters2", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31263349/mercedes-gone-hunted-hunters3", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31263278/verstappen-calls-clarity-messy-track-limits-rules1", 
"https://www.espn.com/f1/story/_/id/31263278/verstappen-calls-clarity-messy-track-limits-rules2", 
"https://www.latimes.com/sports/story/2021-04-18/max-verstappen-lewis-hamilton-emilia-romagna-grand-prix1", 
"https://edition.cnn.com/2021/04/18/motorsport/max-verstappen-lewis-hamilton-imola-gp-spt-intl/index.html1", 
"https://edition.cnn.com/2021/04/18/motorsport/max-verstappen-lewis-hamilton-imola-gp-spt-intl/index.html2", 
"https://edition.cnn.com/2021/04/18/motorsport/max-verstappen-lewis-hamilton-imola-gp-spt-intl/index.html4", 
"https://edition.cnn.com/2021/04/18/motorsport/max-verstappen-lewis-hamilton-imola-gp-spt-intl/index.html6", 
"https://edition.cnn.com/2021/04/18/motorsport/max-verstappen-lewis-hamilton-imola-gp-spt-intl/index.html8"
), class = "data.frame")
```

[image: Here is what my folder looks like, blurred and only small pictures]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images are located at different location. You can try the following code -

```
library(rvest)

lapply(URLs, function(x) {
  x %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes("picture source") %>%
    html_attr("data-srcset") %>% 
    strsplit(',') %>%
    .[[1]] %>%
    na.omit %>%
    trimws %>%
    .[1] -> img
  if(!is.na(img))  download.file(img, paste0('photo', Sys.time(), '.jpeg'))
})
```

Comment: I get this error when I try to run that code:    `   Error in download.file(img, paste0("photo", Sys.time(), ".jpeg")) : 
  cannot open destfile 'photo2021-05-20 12:47:45.jpeg', reason 'Invalid argument'`

Comment: I tried adjusting the code to the following    ```   lapply(urls, function(x) {
  x %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes("img") %>%
    html_attr("data-srcset") %>% 
    strsplit(',') %>%
    .[[1]] %>%
    na.omit %>%
    trimws %>%
    .[1] -> img
  if(!is.na(img))  download.file(img, img.jpeg)
}) ```                        Error message:  Error in .[[1]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: I don't get any error copy-pasting from the code from above. 2 images are downloaded for me because the 3rd one returns `NA`.  I also tried this on fresh R session and it worked the same.

Comment: Do you know why my code is not working properly?  With the updated information.  It doesnt seem like anyone is going to swoop in with an answer despite the bounty.

Comment: @d3hero23 This seems to work for me `Map(download.file, total_urls.2$V1, sprintf('img%d.png', seq_along(total_urls.2$V1)))`. I have got around 45 images in my folder. What does it return for you?

Comment: Thank you for following up.  The code you provided, runs and downloads images, but it still gives me the same issue.  All of the pictures are super small and a lot are scrambled.  I feel I am missing a JSON or CSS code in the download of the pictures.  When I go to the the image urls in my browser they are full size clear pictures that are not downloading through RStudio Another thought is that there is something in my standard RStudio settings that is limiting download size.

Comment: I go to this URL https://a3.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fredesign%2Fassets%2Fimg%2Ficons%2FESPN%2Dicon%2Dnascar.png&w=80&h=80&scale=crop&cquality=40&location=origin Image is small and that is what get's downloaded for me. Can you give me a specific example?

Comment: this url is an example [link] (http://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200809102318-verstappen-celeb-exlarge-169.jpg%22)   I also added a screenshot of the destination folder and how the images are coming through

Comment: I had to change some of your code around but I managed to get my script to work.  I used the xml2 to get the html parsed, for some reason it wasnt working with correctly with the rvest package.  parsed_pages <- replicate(list(), n = length(URLs))
for (k in seq_along(URLs)) parsed_pages[[k]] <- try(xml2::read_html(URLs[k]), silent = TRUE)